# how to use form name variables in the angular $scope

Tags: angularjs

I have a html snippet like this:

```
<div ng-controller="FormCtrl">
   <form  name="{{formName}}"></form>
</div>
```

and a controller like this

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope) {
   $scope.formName = "aFormName";
   $scope.aFormName.$dirty = false // this works
   $scope[formName].$dirty = false // does not work, I get undefined.
});
```

The problem is that I want to get the form based on the variable because the name itself might change later.

Comment: there are several errors here, one of them is that the $scope is not an array, therefor $scope['var'] is not working. you should create your own array for that, like $scope.arr = [];

Comment: I figured out that I had to use ``$scope.formName`` inside the brackets like this: ``$scope[$scope.formName]``, which is the same as writing ``$scope.aFormName`` in this case. And that will not cause any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the `$scope` before the variable name when I tried to get hold of the form. I have to do it like this: `$scope[$scope.formName].$dirty = false`

```
 angular.module('myApp')
      .controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope) {
       $scope.formName = "aFormName";
       $scope.aFormName.$dirty = false // this works
       $scope[$scope.formName].$dirty = false // Now it works
    });
```